# Filière, cursus, parcours, curriculum, tronc commun (université)

Tags: science, académique, université, supérieur

Can the words

> curriculum, cursus, filière, parcours, tronc commun

be used interchangeably in the context of university courses, coursework and the like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les mots « **cursus** », « **filière** »  et « **parcours** » sont utilisés pour signifier « programme d'étude » ; il semble que leurs acceptions relatives au système d'enseignement aient été introduites dans le langage selon l'ordre donné.
Un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cursus+universitaire%2Cfili%C3%A8re+universitaire%2Cparcours+universitaire&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccursus%20universitaire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfili%C3%A8re%20universitaire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparcours%20universitaire%3B%2Cc0) tend à confirmer cela.

On trouve les trois termes utilisés avec le mot « université » dans les termes « cursus/filière/parcours universitaire ». Les trois termes signifient  « programme d'étude universitaire ».

> (TLFi) cursus : [Dans l'Université] Échelonnement graduel des matières enseignées et des diplômes afférents. Il faudrait envisager dès maintenant un nouveau cursus des études
>
> (TLFi)  filière : Succession de degrés à franchir, de voies à suivre pour arriver à un but.
>
> (TLFi)  parcours : Déplacement déterminé accompli ou à accomplir d'un point à un autre; espace correspondant, chemin, distance parcourue

Le mot anglais « **Curriculum** » signifie « **programme d'étude** » en français ; c'est un mot qui existe aussi en français mais il n'a pas cette acception : il est utilisé dans le terme latin « curriculum vitae »  ou en abréviation de ce terme. Pour « programme d'étude » on trouve le mot « cursus » et plus récemment le mot « filière » de sens plus général et que l'on a commencé à utiliser pour signifier « programme d'étude » ; encore plus récemment le mot « parcours » a été ajouté et signifie la même chose.

Comment: Anecdote (véridique) : dans mon école d'ingénieur, j'ai suivi un *cursus* ingénieur de 3 ans, un *parcours* informatique en dernière année et la *filière* conseil en option en dernière année. Les trois termes ont étés utilisés, et désignaient trois regroupement de cours différents. Par contre, je ne suis pas sûr qu'il y ait de consensus général sur la hiérarchie entre ces termes. (Mais pour moi, c'était Cursus > Parcours > filière)

Comment: @JeremyGrand Il semble que je n'ai pas exprimé cette idée d'ordre de façon suffisamment explicite ; l'ordre d'introduction auquel je réfère est l'introduction de ces usage dans la langue française ; c'est d'ailleurs quelque chose que j'avance à partir de ma propre expérience et que je ne peux pas vérifier. Un ngram tend à prouver cela cependant.(ngram dans la suite)

Comment: @JeremyGrand https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cursus+universitaire%2Cfili%C3%A8re+universitaire%2Cparcours+universitaire&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccursus%20universitaire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfili%C3%A8re%20universitaire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparcours%20universitaire%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JeremyGrand Par hiérarchie entre ces termes vous entendez peut être plutôt une sorte d'échelle selon laquelle chacun de  ces termes signifierait la même chose mais ne serait pas appliqué aussi généralement qu'un autre.

Comment: je faisais plutôt référence à ma perception que l'un pouvait être un sous-ensemble d'un autre. Je pense que tout le monde s'accorderait à dire que le cursus est le regroupement le plus vaste tandis qu'une filière serait un sous-groupe du cursus. Dans mon cas, la filière était incluse dans le parcours, mais je ne suis pas certain que cela ça soit compris partout de la même façon.

Comment: Je confirme avec emphase que la hiérarchie des ces différents termes est particulièrement mal définie, car elle dépend non seulement de l'établissement concerné, mais  varie aussi au cours du temps au sein d'un même établissement.

Comment: @Jhor Merci de ce commentaire. Vous pouvez le donner comme réponse.

Answer (score 1):

En addition à la réponse de LPH: le terme "tronc commun" n'est pas du tout un synonyme de "curriculum", "cursus", etc.

Le terme *tronc commun* désigne l'ensemble des cours de base que tous les élèves ou étudiants d'un niveau ou d'une filière doivent suivre, avant de choisir une spécialisation.

Ex:

> Les étudiants en droit suivent un tronc commun les deux premières années, puis s'orientent vers une spécialisation en droit commercial, droit pénal, droit constitutionnel, droit international, etc.